# shadow-fixed bin repo not synchronized?

Tags: ros, buildfarm, deb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Taking `hrpsys` package as an example, as of today:

- Nice [debbuild page](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html) shows `0.0.1-6`.
- In the list of available package binaries at [packages.ros.org](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages), `ros-groovy-hrpsys` remains `0.0.1-1precise-20130823-1025-+0000` that looks outdated.

In addition, I found a package is missing; although `openhrp3` looks built as `0.0.1-6` as well, it's not even listed in `packages.ros.org`.

I just guess it's related to the migration that happened soon after Aug. 23? Or am I missing something and are they actually built and available somewhere? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77781/shadow-fixed-bin-repo-not-synchronized?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

packages.ros.org currently requires a manual sync for updating both shadow-fixed and public.  It's migration is still ongoing.  It should be resolved in the next few weeks, but until then they syncs will be slightly slower.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-09-10**:
Thanks. Is Hydro in the same situation (ie. slower, manual sync) ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-10**:
All packages, until the hosting has finished migration.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-09-16**:
Is this still the case? debbuild page is showing husky_* packages in shadow-fixed, but I can't apt-get them. Is there some way that the manual sync may be triggered?